# Having this problem in solidity can someone help me

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from contract AstTokenSale to address requested.

I have this error and do not know how to fix it can someone help me

here is the code

```
        require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(this)));
```

Answer (score 3):

The error stating that **Invalid implicit conversion from contract AstTokenSale to address requested** meaning that you have to cast to `address` explicitly.

Try this `require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))));`